# Eclipse shortcut "go to line + column"

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

Does anyone know if there is the shortcut "**go to line + column**" in **Eclipse**?

Comment: This shortcut allows you the multicolumn selection, but I am looking for one that carry the cursor to a column

Comment: You can use ctrl+shift+L to show a list of all available shortcuts in Eclipse.

Comment: Goto line is Ctrl + L

Comment: @Javi Pedrera : Consider marking answers as correct ones. Which helps users to identify correct answers and it gives you +5 rep as well

Answer (score 159, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>    Jump to Line Number. To hide/show line numbers, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and select 'Show Line Numbers'
There is no way to go to a particular column according to my knowledge.

On OSX, the shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

It you want more short-cuts, refer http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

Comment: On OSX, the shortcut is `⌘ + L`

Comment: All, If you want more and more shortcuts, in eclipse: ctrl+shift+L.

Answer (score 16):

As you are aware <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> goes to a particular Line, there is also <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to go to the last edit location. The is no key combination in Eclipse to go to a particular Line and Column.

You can use a Keyboard Macro (available as hardware in some keyboards and included as software with some other keyboards). An explanation for Microsoft is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237179 .

A Program like Autohotkey http://www.autohotkey.com/ can also be used.

Answer (score 7):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to jump to specific line number

You can find a large list of eclipse shortcuts here: http://javatutorial.net/eclipse-shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'Command' + L to find line number in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTRL + forward or backward key to jump to the next dot in the same line.
for example, in `System.out.println("test");` you can switch between  System, out and println by using CTRL + forward and backward key.